# swapping column values in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following data frame in spark

```
s s_type o o_type
-----------------  
s1 ss1  o1   oo1   
s2 ss2  o2   oo2
```

I want to swap the columns

```
 s s_type o o_type
 -----------------  
 o1 oo1  s1   ss1   
 o2 oo2  s2   ss2
```

one way is to copy columns `[o, o_type]` into temporary columns `['o_temp','o_type_temp']` 
and then copy the values of `[s,s_type]` into `[o,o_type]` and finally `['o_temp','o_type_temp']` into `[s,s_type]`.

I was wondering if there is a better/more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just use [`select`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.select) with [`pyspark.sql.Column.alias`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Column.alias):

```python
from pyspark.sql.functions import col
df = df.select(
    col("o").alias("s"),
    col("o_type").alias("s_type"),
    col("s").alias("o"),
    col("s_type").alias("o_type")
)
```

For a more generalized solution, you can create a mapping of old name to new name and loop over this in a list comprehension:

```python
# key = old column, value = new column
mapping = {
    "o": "s",
    "o_type": "s_type",
    "s": "o",
    "s_type": "o_type"
}

df = df.select(*[col(old).alias(new) for old, new in mapping.items()])
```